# REST and SOAP requests in the same scenario

Tags: karate

I have a test case where I make a POST call to a REST API, then I copy the generated ID to place it in SOAP request. However, when I put these two calls in one scenario the SOAP request will perform as needed.

Can I make both REST and SOAP calls in the same scenario in Karate?

Thanks.

Comment: You can and must be missing something. Please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue